# Issue openlayers and tilestream

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles

Basically I created a MBtiles using Tilemill and it generates a map with six zooms.
I implement it into tilestream.
I added a layer on the openlayers module(Drupal) in XYZ:

```
site:8888/v2/geography-class/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
```

The problem is this URL sent by openlayers: `site:8888/v2/geography-class/-1/x/x.png`

Each time, whatever the zoom I am on the map, the zoom value always stays at -1, the others values are okay.

If I try to reach `site:8888/v2/geography-class/1/1/1.png` it works.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there is a configuration error on the openlayers side (e.g. not setting the numZoomLevels or setting it to zero, since the maximum zoom level is numZoomLevels-1.

See http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels for configuration details.